# How to performance debug elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I got an already set up (not by me) cluster (actually, one machine) that collects logstash logs from web application. Logs flow isn't extremely active as it's just low/middle loaded web application. However, most of the time elasticsearch process takes 100% CPU; memory doesn't seems to be an issue however, there's lot of free memory on instance.

I can start guessing what wrong, tinkering with cluster settings and index analysers and so on, but I'm wondering:

is there a reliable way to find a performance bottleneck without *guessing*, i.e. some built-in tool that says what exactly takes resources?

Comment: I'd say start with querying [`/_nodes/hot_threads`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-hot-threads.html) in order to see what's being executed when your CPU is high. It's a first step to get insights.

Comment: Check out Marvel, or use this as a guide: https://gist.github.com/pickypg/61ea70e59d3b52a5d6e0